# Python: How to only loop over first 'x' items of a very long list; Writing a Twitter bot with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Noob here. I'm sure this is a simple problem. I'm writing a Twitter bot with tweepy. I've hit a snag. I'm getting a 'Rate limit exceeded' error when I'm calling the api to make a list of followers. From what I understand, this is due to Twitter imposing a limit on calls to the api.

My code snippet:

```
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    follower_ids.append(follower.id)
```

My question: How do I grab the first 'x' items from tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items()?  in range seemed like the obvious solution, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict tweepy's cursor limit like this:

```
# Only iterate through the first 200 followers
for follower in Cursor(api.followers).limit(200):
     follower_ids.append(follower.id)
```

This is pretty explicit in the docs, see [here](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/cursor_tutorial.html).

Comment: How would you then use this to grab the next 200?