# Using Tweepy Documentation to find first x followers

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

Messing around with tweepy. I am creating a desktop application, no callbacks. I want to find the first x followers of a user. Here's what I have so far:

```
consumer_key='...' 
consumer_secret='...' 
access_token='...'
access_token_secret='...'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Basically enough to authenticate my application. Reading the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html), under the 'User methods' section, I see API.followers returns followers 100 at a time. Is there a way to restrict that to x? Like first 5 followers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
api.followers('screen_name')[0:5]
```

This will return the first 5 followers for the specified 'screen_name' profile.

Comment: Thank you @mattcan! If you wouldn't mind me asking, did you find this in the documentation? Or how did you find this? Thank you!

Comment: Apologies I should have provided more info in my answer. I found the call in the documentation -- here's the permalink [link](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.followers). The 'ResultSet' can then be indexed with the use of square brackets.

Comment: I also found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200532/python-how-to-only-loop-over-first-x-items-of-a-very-long-list-writing-a-twi) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455107/the-best-way-to-get-a-list-of-followers-in-python-with-tweepy) to be helpful resources as well. Thank you so much!